# ASP.NetCore code coverage for agent only on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, code-coverage, .net-core

Our product looks like this is composed from two parts:

1. The main program that is running on Windows
2. An ASP.NET Core agent that runs on Linux distros

The main program will send RESTApi call to the agent, the agent will do it's job and report back to the main program.

The question is now, could we get the coverage for a flow starting on the main Windows program -> Linux agent -> main program again?

EDIT: API tests were taken into consideration, and the Windows main application is already tested, as this is an already existing one with a set of functionalities.

What I'm more concerned is the coverage on the Linux agent and also the integration between them. One option would be to somehow make it execute independently using mocked/faked/shimmed/etc data, but I'm not a big fan of these for Integration tests.

Comment: I think a different testing strategy would make more sense. Why not write a set of REST API tests using Postman or `HttpClient` that exercise the agent? The fact that the caller is Windows shouldn't matter. Likewise, you can test the Windows client separately from the API.

Comment: Thanks but these were taken into consideration. I've also updated the question.